# A question on a $2\times 2$ matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, determinant

Suppose we consider an equation $A f=\lambda f^*$. Here $A$ is a differential operator with the general form
$$A=a\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+b g(t)$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $g(t)$ is a complex function of real variable $t$. $f$ is complex function $f=f(t)$, and $f^*$ is its complex conjugate. $\lambda$ is a real number.

We have a complex-conjugated equation $A^* f^*=\lambda f$. In total, we have the matrix form
$$\pmatrix{\ 0\ \ A^*\\
A\ \ 0}\pmatrix{f\\ f^*}=\lambda\pmatrix{f\\ f^*}.$$

It is very easy to see that we have another equation
$$\pmatrix{0\  \ A^*\\
A\ \ 0}\pmatrix{if\\ -if^*}=-\lambda\pmatrix{if\\ -if^*}.$$

Now I will conclude that 
$$-\lambda^2=\det\pmatrix{0\ \ A^*\\
A\ \ 0}=-\det(A^*A).\tag{1}$$

All these look fine to me up to now. But I tried another way in the following and found a disagreement. Writing $A=U+iV$, $f=x+iy$, then we have the following matrix equation
$$\pmatrix{U\ \ -V\\
-V\ \ -U}\pmatrix{x\\ y}=\lambda\pmatrix{x\\ y}.$$ This equation is also associated with another equation 
$$\pmatrix{U\ \ -V\\
-V\ \ -U}\pmatrix{-y\\ x}=-\lambda\pmatrix{-y\\ x}.$$
And I conclude 
$$-\lambda^2=\det\pmatrix{U\ \ -V\\
-V\ \ -U}=-\det (U^2+V^2).$$
However $A^*A=U^2+V^2+i[U,V]$. If both methods are correct then there must be
$$\det (U^2+V^2+i[U,V])=\det(U^2+V^2).\tag{2}$$ 
Is this true? Or there is something wrong in one of these two methods or in both?

For Eq.(2), one possibility that it may be true is that we know 
$$\det(AA^*)=\det(A^*A)$$
which gives
$$\det(U^2+V^2+i[V,U])=\det(U^2+V^2+i[U,V]).$$
Somehow the part $i[V,U]$ or $i[U,V]$ does not contribute in the determinant?

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for your comment. Can you give some more detailes?

Comment: @Mattos There is no guaranty that $A^*A$ must be real, right?

Comment: This looks suspicious. It would extend to "true" matrices, yielding that for each matrix $A$, every eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $|\lambda|^2=\det A^\star A$. And by the way, what is the determinant of a differential operator?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In the post, $Af=\lambda f^*$ should be thought as $Af_n=\lambda_n f_n^*$. But I am as sloppy as most physicists do.  And indeed, the values $\lambda_n$ is always associated with $-\lambda_n$. The determinant of $A$ is understood as an infinite product of its eigenvalues (not the $\lambda_n$s). Of course, $\lambda^2$ can also be understood as $\prod_n \lambda_n^2$.